# How to fix Facebook Autopost Python code error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I was trying to use python code to auto post the content to a particular group but I am getting below error. I am not much good with python but fixed most of the compilation errors. Please help me to fix the below errors. I am using python 3

This is the code I am using to post to facebook

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


username = raw_input('Enter your username: ')
password = raw_input('Enter your password: ')
number_time_post = int(input('Enter the number times post: '))
id_target = int(input('Enter the target ID (page, group, user): '))
content = 'Testing content'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2}
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://m.facebook.com/")
print("Opened facebook")

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('m_login_email')
username_box.send_keys(username)
print("Email Id entered")

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('m_login_password')
password_box.send_keys(password)
print("Password entered")

login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_5')
sleep(10)
login_box.click()

try:
    if driver.find_element_by_id('m_login_email') or \
            driver.find_element_by_id('m_login_password'):
        print("The username or password is incorrect")
        exit(1)
except Exception:
    pass

count = 0
print('Index\t Duration')
start_process = datetime.now()
while number_time_post > 0:
    start = datetime.now()
    count += 1
    driver.get(
        "https://m.facebook.com/{}".format(id_target)
    )
    message_box = None
    try:
        message_box = driver.find_element_by_name('xc_message')
    except Exception:
        message_box = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_0')
    finally:
        if not message_box:
            print('Something went wrong. Please check it again')
            exit(1)

    message_box.send_keys(
         content + ' \n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n' + str(datetime.now().timestamp())
    )
    post_btn = driver.find_element_by_name('view_post')
    sleep(1)
    post_btn.click()

    end = datetime.now()
    duration = end - start
    print("{}\t {}".format(count, duration))
    number_time_post -= 1

end_process = datetime.now()
print('Total\t {}'.format(end_process - start_process))
driver.close()
```

Please finf error below

```
   C:\Users\uday\Downloads\facebook-auto-post-master>python run.py
Enter your username: 11
Enter your password: 11
Enter the number times post: 11
Enter the target ID (page, group, user): 11

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65149/devtools/browser/167f42ea-0a1f-4c63-80da-5ef4f720d7b6
Opened facebook
Email Id entered
Password entered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 34, in <module>
    login_box.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Comment: Is the problem solved? Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error happens at this point `login_box.click()`, with the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

is caused when an element is found, but you cannot interact with it. For instance, you may not be able to click or send keys.

There could be several reasons for this:

1. The element is not visible / not displayed
2. The element is off-screen
3. The element is behind another element or hidden
4. Some other action needs to be performed by the user first to enable it.

I am inclined to think that it could be to do with `point-3` but it would be good for you to evaluate that and find out which is causing the error.

Lastly, the `btn` element on mine is displayed with a different `id`

```
<input value="Log In" aria-label="Log In" data-testid="royal_login_button" type="submit" id="u_0_b">
```

Though it can't be the reason for the cause of your error, it would be good for you to ensure that your `id` values are indeed correct and you are not targetting a wrong element.

Comment: @udaydatrak please accept the answer if your problem is solved. Thanks. see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work&ved=2ahUKEwip5IbaoNTqAhWZSBUIHYf7DVMQjjgwA3oECAoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw14xPABMht6f2y3bJc7g4iU